# How to extend KeyPressHandler to all called class?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I made the GUI of my application using SmartGWT.
If I add a KeyPressHandler like this to my main layout, how can I make it used in all other called classes (new layouts) too.

```
layout.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyName() != null) {
                if (event.getKeyName().equals("f1")) {
                    /*...*/
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't quite understand the question, but as I read between the lines,  you need to add the handler to every layout which you use.

Comment: If @Euclides is right, you don't even need that - just attach it to the RootPanel itself.

Comment: The problem is solved now, thank you guys. Attaching it to the Root Layout was enough. The handler was on an other panel of the Root Layout, therefore the other panels couldn't see.

Answer (score 0):

Like @ColinAlworth says in his comment, if you attach the event to the Root layout in your GUI all his children will trigger the event when it occurs.

Also if you do the check like this:

```
if ("f1".equals(event.getKeyName())) {
     /*...*/
}
```

You dont need to check the null.